# Newton's method is Quasi-Newton when the function is a non-degenerate quadratic

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, newton-raphson

With the update step $\textbf x_{t+1} = \textbf x_t - H_t^{-1}\nabla f(\textbf x_t)$, where $H_t \in \mathbb R^{d\times d}$ is symmetric and satisfies $\nabla f(\textbf 
 x_t) - \nabla f(\textbf x_{t-1}) = H_t(\textbf x_t - \textbf x_{t-1})$, it is called a Quasi-Newton method.

I have to prove that when $H_t = \nabla^2 f(\textbf  x_t)$ (which is the Newton's method), the function $f$ has to be a non-degenerate quadratic of $\textbf x \in \mathbb R^d$, which is of the form: $f(\textbf x) = \dfrac 1 2 \textbf x^\top M \textbf x - \textbf q^\top x + c$

**My attempt**: Starting from  $$\nabla f(\textbf 
 x_t) - \nabla f(\textbf x_{t-1}) = \nabla^2 f(\textbf x_t)(\textbf x_t - \textbf x_{t-1})$$
I transformed it into:
$$\textbf x_t - \nabla^2 f(\textbf x_t)^{-1}\nabla f(\textbf x_t) = \textbf x_{t-1} - \nabla^2 f(\textbf x_t)^{-1}\nabla f(\textbf x_{t-1})$$

It seems to have interesting structure, but I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Interestingly, I struggle to find a solution for the basic case of one dimension $\mathbb R$, which makes me question the validity of this statement. Glad if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear but I think they want you to realize that $\nabla^2 f(\textbf x_t)=M$ and that $M$ needs to be invertible, or something like that.

Comment: @Jap88 yeah, the original problem is that these 2 statements are equivalent: 1. Newton's update step  $\textbf x_{t+1} = \textbf x_t - \nabla^2 f(\textbf x_t)^{-1} \nabla f(x_t)$ define a Quasi-Newton method, and 2. $f(\textbf x)$ is quadratic of $\textbf x$. Proving 2->1 is easy as $H_t = \nabla^2 f(\textbf x_t)$ satisfies the equation I mention at the top. But additional Jacobian or gradient won't help me with 1->2

Comment: Are you sure about your subscripts in your definition of quasi newton method? I think it should be
$$
\nabla f(\textbf 
 x_t) - \nabla f(\textbf x_{t-1}) = H_{t-1}(\textbf x_t - \textbf x_{t-1})
$$
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Newton_method

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 Yes, the definition is taken from here (this is my self-study course, and the exercise is in the exercise part). I can see that somehow the course writer want to derive $H_t$ from the previous iteration, hence they used the secant between $\textbf x_t$ and $\textbf x_{t-1}$ as an approximation

Comment: If that s the case how $H_t$ of the first step derived, when there is no previous step to solve for it?

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 The first 2 step $\textbf x_0$ and $\textbf x_1$ need to be chosen first. I get your point but if we find $H_{t-1}$ then we also don't have $\textbf x_t$ yet as $\textbf x_t = \textbf x_{t-1} - H_{t-1}^{-1}\nabla f(\textbf x_{t-1})$. Ah, I forgot the link to the original definition: https://github.com/epfml/OptML_course/tree/master/lecture_notes

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not an anwser... but hope these may be useful to you

Some general derivations for quasi newton method
$$
\textbf x_{t+1} = \textbf x_t - H_t^{-1}\nabla f(\textbf x_t)\\
\textbf x_{t+1} - \textbf x_t = - H_t^{-1}\nabla f(\textbf x_t)\\
-H_t(\textbf x_{t+1} - \textbf x_t) = \nabla f(\textbf x_t)\\
$$
$$
\nabla f(\textbf   x_{t+1}) - \nabla f(\textbf x_{t}) = H_{t+1}(\textbf x_{t+1} - \textbf x_{t})\\
-H_{t+1}(\textbf x_{t+2} - \textbf x_{t+1}) + H_t(\textbf x_{t+1} - \textbf x_t) = H_{t+1}(\textbf x_{t+1} - \textbf x_{t})\\
H_{t+1}(\textbf x_{t+2} - \textbf x_{t}) = H_t(\textbf x_{t+1} - \textbf x_t)  \\
$$
if we set $H_t=\nabla^2 f(x_{t})$ then
$$
-\nabla^2 f(x_{t})(\textbf x_{t+1} - \textbf x_t) = \nabla f(\textbf x_t)\\
\nabla^2 f(x_{t+1})(\textbf x_{t+2} - \textbf x_{t}) = \nabla^2 f(x_{t})(\textbf x_{t+1} - \textbf x_t)  \\
$$
Then we need to use this to show that $f(x)$ is quadratic..